# Character array will not compile

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

For whatever reason the compiler flags an error on my character array, saying missing termination character.

The funny part is that this array was supplied by my teacher to have us learn about pointers but there's something wrong with his array/string.

```
char Ar[] = {"All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third. All these differ from each other in language, customs and laws. The river Garonne separates the Gauls from the Aquitani; the Marne and the Seine separate them from the Belgae. Of all these, the Belgae are the bravest, because they are furthest from the civilization and refinement of [our] Province, and merchants least frequently resort to them, and import those things which tend to effeminate the mind; and they are the nearest to the Germans, who dwell beyond the Rhine , with whom they are continually waging war; for which reason the Helvetii also surpass the rest of the Gauls in valor, as they contend with the Germans in almost daily battles, when they either repel them from their own territories, or themselves wage war on their frontiers. One part of these, which it has been said that the Gauls occupy, takes its beginning at the river Rhone ; it is bounded by the river Garonne, the ocean, and the territories of the Belgae; it borders, too, on the side of the Sequani and the Helvetii, upon the river Rhine , and stretches toward the north.
From 'Caesar's Conquest of Gaul', Translator. W. A. McDevitte. Translator. W. S. Bohn. 1st Edition. New York. Harper & Brothers. 1869. Harper's New Classical Library. Published under creative commons and available at http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0001"};
```

Comment: are talking about char *Ar[] ?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Maybe you copy/pasted wrong?

Comment: @user233527 It works for me see live demo http://codepad.org/xK30Hp0O

Comment: for what ever reason wasn't working with the brackets. Not sure what went wrong really

Comment: Brackets would normally be used only if you were doing an array of strings rather than a single string.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell how your code is actually formatted.

A string literal cannot span multiple source lines, unless you use backslashes to escape the line endings (but that's not the best method). For example, this:

```
char Ar[] = {"All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which
the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own
language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third."};
```

is a syntax error.  If you want it as one long string with no newline characters, you can use concatenation -- not the `strcat()` function, but a syntax feature whereby adjacent string literals are merged:

```
char Ar[] = {"All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which "
             "the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their "
             "own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third."};
```

Incidentally, the braces are permitted but are not necessary:

```
char Ar[] = "All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which "
            "the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their "
            "own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third.";
```

If you want embedded newline characters, you can add them:

```
char Ar[] = "All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which\n"
            "the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their\n"
            "own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third.";
```

(I've omitted most of the text.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\` at the end of the line. That will also work.

Like:

```
char Ar[] = {"All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third. All these differ from each other in language, customs and laws. The river Garonne separates the Gauls from the Aquitani; the Marne and the Seine separate them from the Belgae. Of all these, the Belgae are the bravest, because they are furthest from the civilization and refinement of [our] Province, and merchants least frequently resort to them, and import those things which tend to effeminate the mind; and they are the nearest to the Germans, who dwell beyond the Rhine , with whom they are continually waging war; for which reason the Helvetii also surpass the rest of the Gauls in valor, as they contend with the Germans in almost daily battles, when they either repel them from their own territories, or themselves wage war on their frontiers. One part of these, which it has been said that the Gauls occupy, takes its beginning at the river Rhone ; it is bounded by the river Garonne, the ocean, and the territories of the Belgae; it borders, too, on the side of the Sequani and the Helvetii, upon the river Rhine , and stretches toward the north.\
From 'Caesar's Conquest of Gaul', Translator. W. A. McDevitte. Translator. W. S. Bohn. 1st Edition. New York. Harper & Brothers. 1869. Harper's New Classical Library. Published under creative commons and available at http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0001"};
```